# Cannot access private member - atomic

Tags: c++

I've got this code:

```
class Animator{
public:


private:
    bool                _running;
    atomic<bool>            _waiting;

};
```

Visual Studio says `Error   2   error C2248: 'std::atomic<bool>::operator =' : cannot access private member declared in class 'std::atomic<bool>'   d:\programmierung\uncertainty\uncertainty\uncertainty\animator.h    113`

I can't see the difference between this class and a minimal class with just the atomic as a member, which works.

Comment: provide complete but minimal example. i don't see the offending line, and your example is *full of unrelevant stuff*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely the assignment operator of your minimal test class is simply never used and therefore not instantiated. If you were to explicitly invoke its assignment operator you should see the same error. An std::atomic does not support assignment to another std::atomic.

Answer (score 3):

You missed the initialisation of the instance variable:

```
#include <atomic>

class Animator
{
public:
    Animator();
private:
    bool _running;
    std::atomic<bool> _waiting;
};

Animator::Animator() : _running(false), _waiting(false) {
}
```

The class `std::atomic` has no assignment operator, but this operator would be used if you use the default constructor without default values.

Comment: The implicitly defined constructor would invoke the assignment operator? Afaik it will invoke the default constructor (which is available).

Comment: If you omit a own default constructor, the compiler creates own constructors and it will also create the default assignment operator. This leads to the problem.